# Using amcl with 360° laser, periodically update without rotating operations

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a robot with 3 lasers. It can update costmaps in 360°. Using amcl's `global_localization` service isn't useful without rotating robot.  How can I calculate robot's pose periodically?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230022/using-amcl-with-360%C2%B0-laser,-periodically-update-without-rotating-operations./) by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 856 on 2016-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`global_localization` is a feature to (re-)initialize amcl's particle filter by spreading estimates throughout the entire map. It is meant to be called only occasionally if the robot gets lost, certainly not "continuously". And yes, it typically requires some motion from the robot to make the filter converge. Calculating the robot's pose continuously is the task of amcl in general, not specifically of the `global_localization` service.
See [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/37794/using-multiple-laserscan/) for using multiple laser scans with amcl.

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-03-24**:
Thank you, Is there a way to update amcl continuously with single laser?

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2016-03-24**:
By continuously do you mean periodically, without moving the robot ?  Not with the default implementation of amcl, the filter is only updated when one of the thresholds controlled by `update_min_d` (distance) and `update_min_a` (angle) is exceeded.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-03-25**:
Yes, I mean periodically without moving robot. Thank you for an answer.